# Переход на flexbox

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Делаю теги для сайта. Раньше использовал `display: inline-block`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нужно, чтобы выравнивание было не слева а по ширине. Такое можно сделать если использовать **flexbox**

```
.myclass {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Но проблема в том, что последняя строка смотрится не красиво с выравниванием по ширине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если вместо `justify-content: space-between` использовать `justify-content: flex-start`, тогда уже не будет выравнивания по ширине при уменьшении разрешения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: Возможно ли в flexbox обратиться к последней строке? Мне нужно чтобы выравнивание было по ширине, а в последней строке по левой стороне. Решение может быть реализовано с помощью **javascript**

Все получилось благодаря ответу пользователя **[Vadim Ovchinnikov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220571/vadim-ovchinnikov)**, за что ему большое спасибо.
Вот как выглядит то что мне нужно было:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотри все свойства flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @yuriy, не нашел того что мне нужно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То же самое как и ответ @Qwertiy только без

```css
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
div {
  text-align: justify;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .25em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Assembler</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>C#</span>
  <span>C++</span>
  <span>CorelDraw</span>
  <span>HTML & CSS</span>
  <span>Java</span>
  <span>JavaScript</span>
  <span>Microsoft Office</span>
  <span>Pascal</span>
  <span>Photoshop</span>
  <span>PHP</span>
  <span>Sketch</span>
  <span>SQL</span>
  <span>База данных</span>
  <span>Графика</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это как раз то что мне нужно, при уменьшении разрешения или добавлении большего количества тегов, выравнивание будет по ширине родительского блока, а последняя строка выравнивается по левой стороне. Спасибо вам большое

Comment: Да не за что:) Приятно было Вам помочь.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  text-align: justify;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .25em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>html</span>
  <span>css</span>
  <span>верстка</span>
  <span>flexbox</span>
  <span>html</span>
  <span>css</span>
  <span>верстка</span>
  <span>flexbox</span>
  <span>html</span>
  <span>css</span>
  <span>верстка</span>
  <span>flexbox</span>
  <span>html</span>
  <span>css</span>
  <span>верстка</span>
  <span>flexbox</span><!-- no spaces here
--></div>
```

Comment: То что у вас получилось я показал на скриншоте №2, в том и проблема, чтобы последний ряд выравнивался не так как все по ширине, а слева

Comment: @Abmin, ну, было немного неровно, но уж точно не по левому краю. Исправил. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1faS6.png

Comment: @Qwertie, на скриншоте №2 у меня не по левому краю, а как и у вас.Это на скриншотах №1 и №3 по левому. Но все равно, спасибо за старания

Comment: @Abmin, наконец-то я внимательно прочитал вопрос. Я специально делал выравнивание по ширине. Надо убрать правило для `div:after`, тогда последняя строка будет по левому краю.